# error when comparing files : IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, offset

I have a program that compares files line by line and calculate the precision by reading two folders a "gold folder" and a "prediction folder).

The extracted files are like this:

```
T1  Task 5 19   nonlinear wave
T2  Task 5 29   nonlinear wave equations
T3  Task 15 29  wave equations
T4  Task 86 111 general analytical method
T5  Task 94 111 analytical method
T6  Task 199 213    minimum stages
T7  Task 268 287    efficient technique
T8  Task 268 298    efficient technique relatingto
```

also the gold files:

```
T1  Process 5 14    oxidation
T2  Material 69 84  Ti-based alloys
T3  Material 186 192    alloys
T4  Task 264 349    understand the role that composition has on the oxidation behavior of Ti-based alloys
T5  Process 312 321 oxidation
T6  Material 334 349    Ti-based alloys
T7  Material 400 415    Ti-based alloys
T8  Material 445 451    alloys
T9  Process 480 489 oxidation
```

The problem is that this code generates this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chedi\Downloads\Semeval\eval.py", line 214, in <module>
    calculateMeasures(folder_gold, folder_pred, remove_anno)
  File "C:\Users\chedi\Downloads\Semeval\eval.py", line 31, in calculateMeasures
    res_full_pred, res_pred, spans_pred, rels_pred = normaliseAnnotations(f_pred, remove_anno)
  File "C:\Users\chedi\Downloads\Semeval\eval.py", line 130, in normaliseAnnotations
    r_g_offs = r_g[1].split(" ")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The error is in the line 130 and in the format of the extracted files, but they seems in the same format: first and second column separated by a tab, the offset by space

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
# by Mattew Peters, who spotted that sklearn does macro averaging not micro averaging correctly and changed it

import os
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support
import sys

def calculateMeasures(folder_gold="data/dev/", folder_pred="data_pred/dev/", remove_anno = ""):
    '''
    Calculate P, R, F1, Macro F
    :param folder_gold: folder containing gold standard .ann files
    :param folder_pred: folder containing prediction .ann files
    :param remove_anno: if set if "rel", relations will be ignored. Use this setting to only evaluate
    keyphrase boundary recognition and keyphrase classification. If set to "types", only keyphrase boundary recognition is evaluated.
    Note that for the later, false positive
    :return:
    '''

    flist_gold = os.listdir(folder_gold)
    res_all_gold = []
    res_all_pred = []
    targets = []

    for f in flist_gold:
        # ignoring non-.ann files, should there be any
        if not str(f).endswith(".ann"):
            continue
        f_gold = open(os.path.join(folder_gold, f), "r")
        try:
            f_pred = open(os.path.join(folder_pred, f), "r")
            res_full_pred, res_pred, spans_pred, rels_pred = normaliseAnnotations(f_pred, remove_anno)
        except IOError:
            print(f + " file missing in " + folder_pred + ". Assuming no predictions are available for this file.")
            res_full_pred, res_pred, spans_pred, rels_pred = [], [], [], []

        res_full_gold, res_gold, spans_gold, rels_gold = normaliseAnnotations(f_gold, remove_anno)

        spans_all = set(spans_gold + spans_pred)

        for i, r in enumerate(spans_all):
            if r in spans_gold:
                target = res_gold[spans_gold.index(r)].split(" ")[0]
                res_all_gold.append(target)
                if not target in targets:
                    targets.append(target)
            else:
                # those are the false positives, contained in pred but not gold
                res_all_gold.append("NONE")

            if r in spans_pred:
                target_pred = res_pred[spans_pred.index(r)].split(" ")[0]
                res_all_pred.append(target_pred)
            else:
                # those are the false negatives, contained in gold but not pred
                res_all_pred.append("NONE")


    #y_true, y_pred, labels, targets
    prec, recall, f1, support = precision_recall_fscore_support(
        res_all_gold, res_all_pred, labels=targets, average=None)
    # unpack the precision, recall, f1 and support
    metrics = {}
    for k, target in enumerate(targets):
        metrics[target] = {
            'precision': prec[k],
            'recall': recall[k],
            'f1-score': f1[k],
            'support': support[k]
        }

    # now micro-averaged
    if remove_anno != 'types':
        prec, recall, f1, s = precision_recall_fscore_support(
            res_all_gold, res_all_pred, labels=targets, average='micro')
        metrics['overall'] = {
            'precision': prec,
            'recall': recall,
            'f1-score': f1,
            'support': sum(support)
        }
    else:
        # just binary classification, nothing to average
        metrics['overall'] = metrics['KEYPHRASE-NOTYPES']

    print_report(metrics, targets)
    return metrics


def print_report(metrics, targets, digits=2):
    def _get_line(results, target, columns):
        line = [target]
        for column in columns[:-1]:
            line.append("{0:0.{1}f}".format(results[column], digits))
        line.append("%s" % results[columns[-1]])
        return line

    columns = ['precision', 'recall', 'f1-score', 'support']

    fmt = '%11s' + '%9s' * 4 + '\n'
    report = [fmt % tuple([''] + columns)]
    report.append('\n')
    for target in targets:
        results = metrics[target]
        line = _get_line(results, target, columns)
        report.append(fmt % tuple(line))
    report.append('\n')

    # overall
    line = _get_line(metrics['overall'], 'avg / total', columns)
    report.append(fmt % tuple(line))
    report.append('\n')

    print(''.join(report))


def normaliseAnnotations(file_anno, remove_anno):
    '''
    Parse annotations from the annotation files: remove relations (if requested), convert rel IDs to entity spans
    :param file_anno:
    :param remove_anno:
    :return:
    '''
    res_full_anno = []
    res_anno = []
    spans_anno = []
    rels_anno = []

    for l in file_anno:
        r_g = l.strip().split("\t")
        r_g_offs = r_g[1].split(" ")

        # remove relation instances if specified
        if remove_anno != "" and r_g_offs[0].endswith("-of"):
            continue

        res_full_anno.append(l.strip())
        # normalise relation instances by looking up entity spans for relation IDs
        if r_g_offs[0].endswith("-of"):
            arg1 = r_g_offs[1].replace("Arg1:", "")
            arg2 = r_g_offs[2].replace("Arg2:", "")
            for l in res_full_anno:
                r_g_tmp = l.strip().split("\t")
                if r_g_tmp[0] == arg1:
                    ent1 = r_g_tmp[1].replace(" ", "_")
                if r_g_tmp[0] == arg2:
                    ent2 = r_g_tmp[1].replace(" ", "_")

            spans_anno.append(" ".join([ent1, ent2]))
            res_anno.append(" ".join([r_g_offs[0], ent1, ent2]))
            rels_anno.append(" ".join([r_g_offs[0], ent1, ent2]))

        else:
            spans_anno.append(" ".join([r_g_offs[1], r_g_offs[2]]))
            keytype = r_g[1]
            if remove_anno == "types":
                keytype = "KEYPHRASE-NOTYPES"
            res_anno.append(keytype)



    for r in rels_anno:
        r_offs = r.split(" ")
        # reorder hyponyms to start with smallest index
        if r_offs[0] == "Synonym-of" and r_offs[2].split("_")[1] < r_offs[1].split("_")[1]:  # 1, 2
            r = " ".join([r_offs[0], r_offs[2], r_offs[1]])

        # Check, in all other hyponym relations, if the synonymous entity with smallest index is used for them.
        # If not, change it so it is.
        if r_offs[0] == "Synonym-of":
            for r2 in rels_anno:
                r2_offs = r2.split(" ")
                if r2_offs[0] == "Hyponym-of" and r_offs[1] == r2_offs[1]:
                    r_new = " ".join([r2_offs[0], r_offs[2], r2_offs[2]])
                    rels_anno[rels_anno.index(r2)] = r_new

                if r2_offs[0] == "Hyponym-of" and r_offs[1] == r2_offs[2]:
                    r_new = " ".join([r2_offs[0], r2_offs[1], r_offs[2]])
                    rels_anno[rels_anno.index(r2)] = r_new

    rels_anno = list(set(rels_anno))

    res_full_anno_new = []
    res_anno_new = []
    spans_anno_new = []

    for r in res_full_anno:
        r_g = r.strip().split("\t")
        if r_g[0].startswith("R") or r_g[0] == "*":
            continue
        ind = res_full_anno.index(r)
        res_full_anno_new.append(r)
        res_anno_new.append(res_anno[ind])
        spans_anno_new.append(spans_anno[ind])

    for r in rels_anno:
        res_full_anno_new.append("R\t" + r)
        res_anno_new.append(r)
        spans_anno_new.append(" ".join([r.split(" ")[1], r.split(" ")[2]]))

    return res_full_anno_new, res_anno_new, spans_anno_new, rels_anno


if __name__ == '__main__':
    folder_gold = "data/dev/"
    folder_pred = "data_pred/dev/"
    remove_anno = ""  # "", "rel" or "types"
    if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
        folder_gold = sys.argv[1]
    if len(sys.argv) >= 3:
        folder_pred = sys.argv[2]
    if len(sys.argv) == 4:
        remove_anno = sys.argv[3]

    calculateMeasures(folder_gold, folder_pred, remove_anno)
```

Comment: Can you write here what you get if you do:\n
 for l in file_anno:
  print l  
that you have inside normaliseAnnotations?

Comment: when i add this     for l in file_anno:  print(l) i have this error   print(l)
           ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: I mean, if you insert `print(l)` right before you call `r_g = l.strip().split("\t")`

Comment: this error: File "C:\Users\narimen\Downloads\Semeval\eval.py", line 130
    r_g = l.strip().split("\t")
                              ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: the code can't be minimal, it is complete, and i give also example of the files compared

Comment: @NarimenDal Please, you did something wrong when you added the `print(l)` line. You either indented wrong or you used a mix of tabs and space.

Comment: i don't know how to fix it, because it test with one tab , 2 tabs, 3 tabs and i have the same error

Comment: you might have used spaces, not tabs in the rest of the file to indent the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having files on my own, I tried with the "gold" file you provided, namely:

```
T1      Process 5 14    oxidation
T2      Material 69 84  Ti-based alloys
T3      Material 186 192    alloys
T4      Task 264 349    understand the role that composition has on the oxidation behavior of Ti-based alloys
T5      Process 312 321 oxidation
T6      Material 334 349    Ti-based alloys
T7      Material 400 415    Ti-based alloys
T8      Material 445 451    alloys
T9      Process 480 489 oxidation
```

For the program to be able to run correctly and not get the error you get of 'list index out of range' in the line of code you mention, it is fundamental that between the first column (the 'Ts') and the second column there is a tab and between the other columns a space. Failing to have a correct file formatted in this way (for example having a space instead of a tab between the first two columns) will give that error. Indeed what really happens in the line

```
r_g = l.strip('\n').split("\t")
```

is that first the newline gets removed at the end of the line, and than the line is splitted by tab. This means that the line gets splitted in two elements, which make up the list `r_g`. In this case `r_g_offs` can be calculated correctly and will contain a list of elements which are all the columns but the first. In some cases then, this will be used later for example in
`spans_anno.append(" ".join([r_g_offs[1], r_g_offs[2]]))`
just to mention one.

Let's look at the case which doesn't work and let's try to understand why.
If the file .ann (gold) is not formatted in this way:

> T1\tProcess  (tab between)

but instead is

> T1 Process  (space)

the code

```
r_g = l.strip('\n').split("\t")
```

will produce a list of just one element and not of two, e.g.

> r_g = ['T1 Process ...']

In this case, `r_g` has only one element, the element `r_g[0]` so when one tries to access an element that doesn't exist (`r_g[1]`) via

```
r_g_offs = r_g[1].split()
```

one will get an

> IndexError: list index out of range

---

There exists another case in which you could get the aforementioned error.
In the case of empty line at the end of the file, `r_g = ['']`, which means `r_g` is a list of only one element. Now, similar to the previous case, when the script executes the line `r_g_offs = r_g[1].split()`, will try to access `r_g[1]`, which doesn't exist since the only element in the list in this case is `r_g[0]` and you will get the 'list index out of range' error.

---

The code I can run:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# by Mattew Peters, who spotted that sklearn does macro averaging not
# micro averaging correctly and changed it

import os
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support
import sys

def calculateMeasures(folder_gold="data/dev/", folder_pred="data_pred/dev/", remove_anno=""):
    '''
    Calculate P, R, F1, Macro F
    :param folder_gold: folder containing gold standard .ann files
    :param folder_pred: folder containing prediction .ann files
    :param remove_anno: if set if "rel", relations will be ignored. Use this setting to only evaluate
    keyphrase boundary recognition and keyphrase classification. If set to "types", only keyphrase boundary recognition is evaluated.
    Note that for the later, false positive
    :return:
    '''

    flist_gold = os.listdir(folder_gold)
    res_all_gold = []
    res_all_pred = []
    targets = []

    for f in flist_gold:
        # ignoring non-.ann files, should there
        # be any
        if not str(f).endswith(".ann"):
            continue
        f_gold = open(os.path.join(folder_gold, f), "r")
        try:
            f_pred = open(os.path.join(folder_pred, f), "r")
            res_full_pred, res_pred, spans_pred, rels_pred = normaliseAnnotations(f_pred, remove_anno)
        except IOError:
            print(f + " file missing in " + folder_pred + ". Assuming no predictions are available for this file.")
            res_full_pred, res_pred, spans_pred, rels_pred = [], [], [], []

        res_full_gold, res_gold, spans_gold, rels_gold = normaliseAnnotations(f_gold, remove_anno)

        spans_all = set(spans_gold + spans_pred)

        for i, r in enumerate(spans_all):
            if r in spans_gold:
                target = res_gold[spans_gold.index(r)].split(" ")[0]
                res_all_gold.append(target)
                if not target in targets:
                    targets.append(target)
            else:

                res_all_gold.append("NONE")

            if r in spans_pred:
                target_pred = res_pred[spans_pred.index(r)].split(" ")[0]
                res_all_pred.append(target_pred)
            else:

                res_all_pred.append("NONE")

        #y_true, y_pred, labels, targets
        prec, recall, f1, support = precision_recall_fscore_support(res_all_gold, res_all_pred, labels=targets, average=None)
        metrics = {}
        for k, target in enumerate(targets):
            metrics[target] = {
                'precision': prec[k],
                'recall': recall[k],
                'f1-score': f1[k],
                'support': support[k]
            }

        # now
        # micro-averaged
        if remove_anno != 'types':
            prec, recall, f1, s = precision_recall_fscore_support(res_all_gold, res_all_pred, labels=targets, average='micro')
            metrics['overall'] = {
                'precision': prec,
                'recall': recall,
                'f1-score': f1,
                'support': sum(support)
            }
        else:
            # just
            # binary
            # classification,
            # nothing
            # to
            # average
            metrics['overall'] = metrics['KEYPHRASE-NOTYPES']

    print_report(metrics, targets)
    return metrics

def print_report(metrics, targets, digits=2):
    def _get_line(results, target, columns):
        line = [target]
        for column in columns[:-1]:
            line.append("{0:0.{1}f}".format(results[column], digits))
        line.append("%s" % results[columns[-1]])
        return line

    columns = ['precision', 'recall', 'f1-score', 'support']

    fmt = '%11s' + '%9s' * 4 + '\n'
    report = [fmt % tuple([''] + columns)]
    report.append('\n')
    for target in targets:
        results = metrics[target]
        line = _get_line(results, target, columns)
        report.append(fmt % tuple(line))
    report.append('\n')

    # overall
    line = _get_line(
    metrics['overall'], 'avg / total', columns)
    report.append(fmt % tuple(line))
    report.append('\n')

    print(''.join(report))

def normaliseAnnotations(file_anno, remove_anno):
    '''
    Parse annotations from the annotation files: remove relations (if requested), convert rel IDs to entity spans
    :param file_anno:
    :param remove_anno:
    :return:
    '''
    res_full_anno = []
    res_anno = []
    spans_anno = []
    rels_anno = []

    for l in file_anno:
        print(l)
        print(l.strip('\n'))
        r_g = l.strip('\n').split("\t")
        print(r_g)
        print(len(r_g))
        r_g_offs = r_g[1].split()
        print(r_g_offs)
        if remove_anno != "" and r_g_offs[0].endswith("-of"):
            continue

        res_full_anno.append(l.strip())

        if r_g_offs[0].endswith("-of"):
            arg1 = r_g_offs[1].replace("Arg1:", "")
            arg2 = r_g_offs[2].replace("Arg2:", "")
            for l in res_full_anno:
                r_g_tmp = l.strip().split("\t")
                if r_g_tmp[0] == arg1:
                    ent1 = r_g_tmp[1].replace(" ", "_")
                if r_g_tmp[0] == arg2:
                    ent2 = r_g_tmp[1].replace(" ", "_")

            spans_anno.append(" ".join([ent1, ent2]))
            res_anno.append(" ".join([r_g_offs[0], ent1, ent2]))
            rels_anno.append(" ".join([r_g_offs[0], ent1, ent2]))

        else:
            spans_anno.append(" ".join([r_g_offs[1], r_g_offs[2]]))
            keytype = r_g[1]
            if remove_anno == "types":
                keytype = "KEYPHRASE-NOTYPES"
            res_anno.append(keytype)

    for r in rels_anno:
        r_offs = r.split(" ")
# reorder hyponyms to start with smallest index
# 1, 2
        if r_offs[0] == "Synonym-of" and r_offs[2].split("_")[1] < r_offs[1].split("_")[1]:
            r = " ".join([r_offs[0], r_offs[2], r_offs[1]])
        if r_offs[0] == "Synonym-of":
            for r2 in rels_anno:
                r2_offs = r2.split(" ")
                if r2_offs[0] == "Hyponym-of" and r_offs[1] == r2_offs[1]:
                    r_new = " ".join([r2_offs[0], r_offs[2], r2_offs[2]])
                    rels_anno[rels_anno.index(r2)] = r_new

                if r2_offs[0] == "Hyponym-of" and r_offs[1] == r2_offs[2]:
                    r_new = " ".join([r2_offs[0], r2_offs[1], r_offs[2]])
                    rels_anno[rels_anno.index(r2)] = r_new

    rels_anno = list(set(rels_anno))

    res_full_anno_new = []
    res_anno_new = []
    spans_anno_new = []

    for r in res_full_anno:
        r_g = r.strip().split("\t")
        if r_g[0].startswith("R") or r_g[0] == "*":
            continue
        ind = res_full_anno.index(r)
        res_full_anno_new.append(r)
        res_anno_new.append(res_anno[ind])
        spans_anno_new.append(spans_anno[ind])

    for r in rels_anno:
        res_full_anno_new.append("R\t" + r)
        res_anno_new.append(r)
        spans_anno_new.append(" ".join([r.split(" ")[1], r.split(" ")[2]]))

    return res_full_anno_new, res_anno_new, spans_anno_new, rels_anno

if __name__ == '__main__':
    folder_gold = "data/dev/"
    folder_pred = "data_pred/dev/"
    remove_anno = ""  # "", "rel" or "types"
    if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
        folder_gold = sys.argv[1]
    if len(sys.argv) >= 3:
        folder_pred = sys.argv[2]
```

> From the two cases shown above, we can conclude that the script is very sensible to how the file are formatted/written (tab, spaces and no empty line at the end), so care will be needed when producing those files and feeding them to the main script.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, i put the text files in the format: Ts \tab Porcess \s23\s32\s oxidation, but i have the same error! i don' t understand why i can't use the print?

Comment: That's strange, I can run it...I will share my code in the answer!

Comment: when i use `print(r_g_offs)` the result is correct `  ['Task', '0', '14', 'Nuclear', 'theory']`  i don't understand why it generate the error  !! IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: At which line it generates that error for you? Because I can run without errors...

Comment: `File "C:\scienceie2017_train\test.py", line 137, in normaliseAnnotations
    r_g_offs = r_g[1].split()
IndexError: list index out of range` this is what are dispalyed, i think in the end of the file there is an empty line wich generate the error: T1      Task 0 14       Nuclear theory

T1      Task 0 14       Nuclear theory
['T1', 'Task 0 14', 'Nuclear theory']
3
['Task', '0', '14']
T2      Task 23 36      major efforts

T2      Task 23 36      major efforts
['T2', 'Task 23 36', 'major efforts']
3
['Task', '23', '36'].............
this is the last line (the empty line) ['']
1

Comment: I'll include this corner case in the answer, let me update.

Comment: I eliminate the space and OK i understand the error, because i have many files, it is about some caracter like ** ’ and “...** , the error message  File "C:\scienceie2017_train\test.py", line 132, in normaliseAnnotations
    print(l)
  File "C:\Users\chedi\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 25-26: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: That's really another error, which you can write about in another question. The error mentioned in this question should be covered for the example files you provided in the question and the kind of error you were getting.

Comment: the solution is to set encoding in windows console with  `chcp 65001
set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8`

Comment: @NarimenDal I'm glad you solved also this other error!